# Drawing the Dominica Flag (Not Dominican) Using Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw the Dominica Flag (not to be confused with dominican flag) using python turtle. I currently have everything in the code except for the bird (which I have no idea how to do either). I also can't seem to figure out how to get 10 stars to show up properly inside the red circle with NO LINES inside the stars. It would be great if I could get some tips on how to center the stars inside the circle as well as how I would go about drawing the bird in the middle. Thanks!

Here is an image of it:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle()


def drawRect():
    alex.speed(0)
    alex.up()
    alex.fillcolor("green")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.setpos(-250, -100)
    alex.down()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(500)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(300)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()
drawRect()

def drawLines():
    alex.speed(0)
    alex.fillcolor("yellow")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(-250, 70)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(500)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

    alex.fillcolor("black")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(-250, 40)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(500)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

    alex.pencolor("white")
    alex.fillcolor("white")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(-250, 10)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(500)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

    alex.speed(0)
    alex.fillcolor("yellow")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(-40, -100)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(300)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

    alex.speed(0)
    alex.fillcolor("black")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(-10, -100)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(300)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

    alex.speed(0)
    alex.pencolor("white")
    alex.fillcolor("white")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(20, -100)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(30)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(300)
        alex.left(90)
    alex.end_fill()

drawLines()

def drawCircle():
    alex.speed(0)
    alex.up()
    alex.setpos(10, -50)
    alex.down()
    alex.fillcolor("red")
    alex.begin_fill()
    alex.circle(100)
    alex.end_fill()
drawCircle()

def drawStars():
    alex.speed(0)
    alex.pencolor("green")
    alex.fillcolor("green")
    alex.begin_fill()

    for i in range(5):
        alex.forward(20)
        alex.right(144)

def makeStars():
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(25, -10)
    alex.pendown()
    for i in range(11):
        drawStars()
        alex.left(35)
        alex.penup()
        alex.forward(45)
        alex.pendown()

makeStars()
```

Comment: you could just display it: `image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/dominica-flag.png')`

Comment: Just for getting the flag displayed, looks like a great use case for SVG (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Flag_of_Dominica.svg is liberally licensed). You might even be able to turn its paths into turtle commands if this is some kind of turtle learning exercise, though that's not going to be trivial (first you look up SVG path syntax, then you convert between coordinate scales and ways of describing shapes...).

Comment: It is a turtle learning exercise. So I cannot just get a picture and display it. I need to make it as detailed as possible starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework, or something you're doing for your own self-learning? Either way, drawing that parrot is **not** going to be easy! The SVG that twotwotwo linked uses over 40 distorted ellipses and about 30 linear paths; I guess it was created in a vector drawing program (eg Inkscape).

Even if you aren't familiar with SVG that file may still be useful to you. Since it's from Wikipedia, I assume it's a good representation of the current official Dominica flag, so the sizes, positions, and colours of the elements should be fairly accurate.

Here are some of the colours from that file:

```
yellow: "#fcd116"
green: "#006b3f"
red: "#d41c30"
```

The turtle module understands colours in that format.

...

Now, onto your current problems.

I haven't used turtle graphics for *many* years, but you inspired me to install tkinter so that I could tinker with your code. The first problem I noticed was `alex.left(35)` in `makeStars()`, that should be 36, since 360°/10 = 36°.

I tried various things to get the star circle correctly centred, and the stars aligned properly, but after an hour or so of frustration I gave up on the simple drawing commands. I'm sure it'd be a breeze for a turtle expert, but I decided on a slightly more trigonometric approach.

Due to the way the turtle module does filling, there's no easy way to draw filled stars. Some vector drawing systems have alternate fill modes to get around that problem, but turtle doesn't appear to do so. So you either have to fill in the centre of the star with a pentagon, or draw the star as a 10 sided polygon.

I have written some code that draws the filled stars properly centered and aligned. The sizes in my code aren't *exactly* the same as those in the SVG, but they're quite close. I'm happy to post my code here if this is for your own self-learning exercise. OTOH, if this is for homework I probably shouldn't post the whole thing...

PS. It makes it easier to read code if you define all your functions first, and then call them at the bottom of your program (preferably inside a `main()` function). Interspersing the function calls with the function definitions is a bit messy.